# Undefined symbol : SDL_FreeSurface

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-1.2

I have this error :

> undefined symbol: SDL_FreeSurface

I have tried to call the method `void SDL_FreeSurface(SDL_Surface* surface);` where I needed to free my surface but this doesn't seems to solve the problem.

I linked the SDL 1.2 with the `-lSDL`, and `-lSDL_image` option (`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_image`).

I use dynamic libraries.

Comment: Did you also link -lSDLmain? It is important to link on this order:  -lSDLmain -lSDL

Answer (score 0):

I got it :

On Ubuntu, you need to put the -l$(LIB_NAME) at the end of the compilation's line like this :

```
gcc *.cpp [OPTIONS] -l$(LIB_NAME)
```

Comment: You always need to link libraries before you use functions from them.